# Question about joint cdf calculated by ratio of areas

Tags: probability, statistics

If a point $(X,Y)$ is equally likely to fall anywhere in a circle/triangle/square or whatever, is it true that the joint CDF of $X Y$ is the ratio of bounded area (bounded by $X\le x$,and $Y\le y$) and the total area (bounded by the range of $x$ and $y$)? Because I calculated the joint CDF using double integral of joint PDF and find it is the same as the ratio. Could someone explain the reason? And is it also true that if the joint PDF is a constant, then the CDF is just that ratio multiplied by that constant value?

Comment: It is by definition of the CDF, i.e., $Pr(X<x, Y<y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.   When 2D points are uniformly distributed in a shape, $S$, the CDF is:

$$F_{X.Y}(s,t) = \iint\limits_{(x,y)\in S, x\leq s, y\leq t} \dfrac 1{\lvert S\rvert}\operatorname d(x,y)$$

which is indeed the *proportionate* area of the shape below the horizontal line $x=s$ and left of the vertical line $y=t$.